# Transfer large amount of data from DB2 to Oracle?

Tags: oracle, db2, etl, data-transfer

I need every day to transfer large amounts of data (about several millions records) from db2 to oracle database. Could u suggest the best perfoming method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 will allow you to select Oracle as a replication target.  This is probably the most efficient and easiest way to do it every day, it also removes the "intermediate container" objection that you have.

See [this introduction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ii.db2udb.replication.intro.doc/prod_overview/iiyrcintrssql.html) (and more from the documentation online) for more.

Comment: It seems this is what I need.

Comment: No doubt this will work. In my experience this will be much, much slower than a file export/import.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only talking speed then do this.

Time how long it takes to dump the DB2 data to a flatfile.

Time how long it takes to suck that flatfile into Oracle.

there's your baseline and it's free. If you can beat that with an ETL tool, then decide if the cost of the tool is worth it.

For a simple ETL like this, there's little that I've found that can beat this on time.

The downside of this is just general file manipulation BS...

- how do you know when to read from the file
- how do you know that you got all the rows
- how do you resume when something breaks

All those little "niceties" usually get paid for with speed. Of course, I'm joking a bit. They aren't always a little nicety. They are often essential for a smooth running process.

Comment: And if I do not want to have an intermediate files. I need database-to-database interaction. So answers to your questions: 1. Reading is carried out on schedule 2. When copied all rows from table 3. Mb when rising some kind of exception? PS: sorry for my english

Comment: You asked for the best performing method. Now you want to eliminate the best performing method. People don't mind helping so long as their help isn't a waste of time. If this was a limitation, you should have included that in the question.

Comment: well, I realized my mistake, sorry, that does not have this limitation in my question. I thought that there should be a more efficient way than the intermediate container and therefore does not mentioned this restriction.

Comment: Depends on your definition of efficient. What does it mean to you?

Comment: Time costs, I need to finish data transfer during given time window. I thought that when processes of reading data in db2 and writing data in oracle perfomed same time (parallel) would be faster than when at first all data exported from db2 to file, then file transfered and then imported from file to oracle.

Comment: Databases connecting to each other do so over sub-optimal protocols. These protocols have to support ACID and two-phase commits, etc. File dump/file import are all completely optimized. If you want to go with Michael's answer as the best, that's ok. But you should do as I suggested. Do one export, time it. Do that import, time it. There's the bar. Your better direct method will be either faster or slower. If it's slower, it might still be ok. But you'll know by how much.

Answer (score 0):

Dump out data to delimited file.  Load to Oracle via DIRECT load sqlldr job.  Not sexy, but fast.  If you can be on same subnet that would be best (pushing data across the network is not what you want).  Set this up on a cron, add email alerts on errors